# How can I turn off Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have created a simple Spring web service using Gradle.

This is my **Application.java** code.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my **TestController.java** code:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String test() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

When I launch the application and try to access it through a browser, it asks me for an username and a password. The problem is that I have not implemented any authentication mechanism and I have no idea how to access the application. How can I turn off the authentication?

Comment: In the Spring Boot properties reference (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) there is a "security.ignored" property, which defaults to false. There is no description for this property, but based on its name it could do the trick ...

Comment: It is only enabled if you have Spring Security on your classpath. Spring Boot does auto configuration for you (you can even remove the `@enableWebMvc` annotation as Spring Boot enables it for you when it detects Spring WebMVC on the classpath. The username is user and the password is printed to the console (if you still want to use it). All in all it seems you are using spring boot but don't understand what it can do for you.

Comment: Thank you. I have just realised that I have accidentally added spring-boot-starter-security to my gradle build, so removing it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question with at least a suggestion for a solution that I will turn into an answer so that the question can be "closed".

Removing `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency would be a solution.